# Magento 2.4 pub folder in .htaccess

Tags: magento

I installed magento 2.4 on a testserver where i can not change the root folder to pub. I changed the .htaccess in the root to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I can see the site logo and menu, but the content part gives a 404

When i add pub/ to the url everything is showing.

How to changed the .htaccess so that adding /pub is not nesseccary

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]

You missed the "/"